# Mocks with jsonpath and mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, jsonpath, mockmvc

Any idea why this isn't compiling, the ".andExpect(JsonPath("$.title", is("Test Blog Entry")))" is causing the issue in eclipse luna.  works fine without it. It is a springmvc tutorial app and the pom is also attached below.
package com.spring.angular.tutorial.web;

```
@InjectMocks
private BlogEntryController blogEntryController;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(blogEntryController).build();
}

@Test
public void viewTest() throws Exception{
    //mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print());
    mockMvc.perform(post("/")
            .content("{\"title\":\"Test Blog Entry coming in\"}")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                        
    ).andExpect(JsonPath("$.title", is("Test Blog Entry")))
    .andDo(print());
}
```

}

the pom is:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    spring_angular_tutorial
    spring_angular_tutorial
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jackson dependencies NOTE: needed to remove type bundle for maven to accept them-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Ok, got the desired outcome by replacing 

.andExpect(JsonPath("$.title", is("Test Blog Entry"))) with
andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value("Test Blog Entry"))

Not sure why the original doesn't work as it is the same syntex used in the tutorial, perhaps the jsonPath library has changed (0.9.x in the tutorial and I am using 2.0)?

Not quite an answer but posting in case someone else has the same issue, woudl still be interested in a better explanation if anyone knows.